# WCF client proxy class renaming problem

Tags: wcf, automated-refactoring

Perhaps others have encountered the same problem.  It seems the default class name for a WCF client proxy is Service1Client.  When I delete the service reference and recreate it the name keeps coming up the same.  (Although it does give me the opportunity to name the namespace.)

When I chose Refactor/Rename on Service1Client (ie: the class name for the proxy), it fails with the following message:

The file 'Service References\myNameSpace\References.cs' could not be refactored.  The current object is autogenerated by the Wcf Client Generator and cannot be renamed.

Comment: The name is derived from the name of the service on the server side - if you call your service `MyService`, then the client will be `MyServiceClient`. It's a convention and you should just leave that alone.

Comment: Great answer.  Please post it as an answer if you get a chance.  It may be a convention but appending "Proxy" instead of appending "Client" would have been a better convention, no?

Comment: It seems that in my most recent experiment what actually happened was that the proxy class name is created by .NET by taking the interface name, dropping the "I", and appending "Client".  Of course if your class and interface have similar names, it might be less apparent where the root of the name came from.